# How to compare two dataframes in pandas without for loop?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to compare two dataframes and find pairs of rows with the same `sample`, `chr` and `family` and the value in `pos` in `just_r` dataframe should be in range between `just_f pos` and `just_f pos + 1000`. My solution is based on two loops with itertuples which is not effective (my data has thousands of rows and it takes so much time). Maybe someone could help me to find a more smart solution? Here is the part of my input data, expected output and my code below. Thanks a lot!

**just_f**

```
sample  chr pos strand  family  order   support comment frequency
2   NC_025812.2 9831    .   Tourist|7   Tourist F   -   0,562
2   NC_025812.2 12038   .   Tourist|7   Tourist F   -   1,000
5   NC_025812.2 12040   .   Tourist|7   Tourist F   -   1,000
12  NC_025812.2 12042   .   Tourist|7   Tourist F   -   1,000
11  NC_025812.2 30758   .   uc|32   uc  F   -   0,547
12  NC_025812.2 49544   .   uc|10   uc  F   -   0,112
11  NC_025812.2 56184   .   hAT|9   hAT F   -   0,997
5   NC_025812.2 56246   .   hAT|9   hAT F   -   0,756
3   NC_025812.2 56265   .   hAT|9   hAT F   -   1,000
12  NC_025812.2 56268   .   hAT|9   hAT F   -   1,000
```

**just_r**

```
5   NC_025812.2 12396   .   Tourist|7   Tourist R   -   0,975
2   NC_025812.2 12433   .   Tourist|7   Tourist R   -   0,935
12  NC_025812.2 12478   .   Tourist|7   Tourist R   -   0,887
12  NC_025812.2 28943   .   Tourist|7   Tourist R   -   0,610
5   NC_025812.2 28947   .   Tourist|7   Tourist R   -   0,490
2   NC_025812.2 51483   .   Mutator|24  Mutator R   -   0,422
5   NC_025812.2 56713   .   hAT|9   hAT R   -   0,925
11  NC_025812.2 56737   .   hAT|9   hAT R   -   1,000
3   NC_025812.2 56778   .   hAT|9   hAT R   -   0,891
12  NC_025812.2 56800   .   hAT|9   hAT R   -   0,965
```

**f_r_pairs**

```
sample  chr pos strand  family  order   support comment frequency
2   NC_025812.2 12038   .   Tourist|7   Tourist F   -   1.0
2   NC_025812.2 12433   .   Tourist|7   Tourist R   -   0.935
5   NC_025812.2 12040   .   Tourist|7   Tourist F   -   1.0
5   NC_025812.2 12396   .   Tourist|7   Tourist R   -   0.975
12  NC_025812.2 12042   .   Tourist|7   Tourist F   -   1.0
12  NC_025812.2 12478   .   Tourist|7   Tourist R   -   0.887
11  NC_025812.2 56184   .   hAT|9   hAT F   -   0.997
11  NC_025812.2 56737   .   hAT|9   hAT R   -   1.0
5   NC_025812.2 56246   .   hAT|9   hAT F   -   0.756
5   NC_025812.2 56713   .   hAT|9   hAT R   -   0.925
3   NC_025812.2 56265   .   hAT|9   hAT F   -   1.0
3   NC_025812.2 56778   .   hAT|9   hAT R   -   0.891
12  NC_025812.2 56268   .   hAT|9   hAT F   -   1.0
12  NC_025812.2 56800   .   hAT|9   hAT R   -   0.965
```

```
import pandas as pd

df_raw = pd.read_csv('1-DH-to-12-RO.NC_teinsertions.txt', sep="\t", decimal=',')
df_sort = df_raw.sort_values(by=['chr', 'pos', 'sample'])

just_f = df_sort[(df_sort["support"] == 'F')]
just_r = df_sort[(df_sort["support"] == 'R')]

f_r_pairs = pd.DataFrame(columns=just_f.columns)

# choosing rows for reference TE insertions (having pairs with F and R in range 1000 bp)
for f in just_f.itertuples():
    for r in just_r.itertuples():
        if f.sample == r.sample and f.chr == r.chr and f.family == r.family and r.pos in range(f.pos, f.pos + 1000):
            f_r_pairs = f_r_pairs.append(pd.DataFrame([f]))
            f_r_pairs = f_r_pairs.append(pd.DataFrame([r]))
```

Comment: Because you have split df_raw you then use nested loops going over each row of each of the 2 DFs, which is a lot of comparisons. Instead maybe you could use groupby on the original DF grouping on the columns which need to be the same then go over the grouped rows checking for your condition to filter pairs of rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join the two dataframes based on the matching keys, then filter for the rows that satisfy the `pos` condition.

There are 2 functions that you can use: `join` and `merge`. `merge` is the more flexible one:

```py
f_r_pairts = (
    just_f.merge(just_r, on=["sample", "chr", "family"], suffixes=("_f", "_r"))
    .query("pos_f <= pos_r <= pos_f + 1000")
)
```

Comment: Thank you, @Code Different, the result is what I expected and works VERY fast. Could you just help me with how to receive the output as in my example `f_r_pairs` (not as the merged dataframe with suffixes)?