# Effective comparing two dataframes with Pandas without iteration

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, compare

I need to find rows in `UNPAIRED` dataframe (and concat it finally with `FR` dataframe) with the same `chr` and `family` and the value in `pos` in `UNPAIRED` dataframe should be in range between `FR pos - 200` and `FR pos + 200` AND IMPORTANT: `sample` in `UNPAIRED` should be DIFFERENT THAN `sample` in `FR` dataframe. Here are the input dataframes and expected output (`NONREF_ALL`):

`FR`

```
        sample          chr       pos strand       family     order support comment  frequency
0            1  NC_025812.2      9760      .    Tourist|7   Tourist      FR       -      0.833
1            9  NC_025812.2      9803      .    Tourist|7   Tourist      FR       -      0.951
2            5  NC_025812.2      9810      .    Tourist|7   Tourist      FR       -      0.819
3            7  NC_025812.2      9811      .    Tourist|7   Tourist      FR       -      0.942
4            8  NC_025812.2      9821      .    Tourist|7   Tourist      FR       -      1.000
5           10  NC_025812.2      9843      .    Tourist|7   Tourist      FR       -      1.000
6            4  NC_025812.2      9861      .    Tourist|7   Tourist      FR       -      0.978
7            6  NC_025812.2      9861      .    Tourist|7   Tourist      FR       -      0.770
8            6  NC_025812.2      9969      .   Mutator|21   Mutator      FR       -      0.695
9            3  NC_025812.2     12176      .    Tourist|7   Tourist      FR       -      0.973
10           4  NC_025812.2     12176      .    Tourist|7   Tourist      FR       -      1.000
11           6  NC_025812.2     12176      .    Tourist|7   Tourist      FR       -      1.000
12           8  NC_025812.2     12176      .    Tourist|7   Tourist      FR       -      1.000
13           9  NC_025812.2     12176      .    Tourist|7   Tourist      FR       -      0.959
14          10  NC_025812.2     12176      .    Tourist|7   Tourist      FR       -      1.000
15          11  NC_025812.2     12176      .    Tourist|7   Tourist      FR       -      0.816
16           7  NC_025812.2     12177      .    Tourist|7   Tourist      FR       -      1.000
17           1  NC_025812.2     12184      .    Tourist|7   Tourist      FR       -      1.000
18          11  NC_025812.2     28982      .    Tourist|7   Tourist      FR       -      0.797
19           9  NC_025812.2     50305      .         uc|5        uc      FR       -      1.000
20           7  NC_025812.2     50314      .         uc|5        uc      FR       -      1.000
21           1  NC_025812.2     50327      .         uc|5        uc      FR       -      1.000
22           8  NC_025812.2     50327      .         uc|5        uc      FR       -      1.000
23          10  NC_025812.2     50329      .         uc|5        uc      FR       -      1.000
24           6  NC_025812.2     50336      .         uc|5        uc      FR       -      0.757
25           5  NC_025812.2     50339      .         uc|5        uc      FR       -      0.882
26           4  NC_025812.2     50353      .         uc|5        uc      FR       -      1.000
27           2  NC_025812.2     50385      .         uc|5        uc      FR       -      0.712
28          10  NC_025812.2     51457      .   Mutator|24   Mutator      FR       -      1.000
29           7  NC_025812.2     51466      .   Mutator|24   Mutator      FR       -      1.000
30           4  NC_025812.2     51475      .   Mutator|24   Mutator      FR       -      1.000
31           1  NC_025812.2     51481      .   Mutator|24   Mutator      FR       -      1.000
32           5  NC_025812.2     51481      .   Mutator|24   Mutator      FR       -      0.280
33           6  NC_025812.2     51481      .   Mutator|24   Mutator      FR       -      0.307
34           8  NC_025812.2     51481      .   Mutator|24   Mutator      FR       -      1.000
35           9  NC_025812.2     51481      .   Mutator|24   Mutator      FR       -      0.893
```

`UNPAIRED`

```
        sample          chr       pos strand       family     order support comment  frequency
0            6  NC_025812.2       889      .       hAT|21       hAT       R       -      1.000
1           12  NC_025812.2       899      .       hAT|21       hAT       R       -      1.000
2            2  NC_025812.2      9831      .    Tourist|7   Tourist       F       -      0.562
3           11  NC_025812.2     28783      .    Tourist|7   Tourist       F       -      0.412
4           12  NC_025812.2     28943      .    Tourist|7   Tourist       R       -      0.610
5            5  NC_025812.2     28947      .    Tourist|7   Tourist       R       -      0.490
6           11  NC_025812.2     30758      .        uc|32        uc       F       -      0.547
7           12  NC_025812.2     49544      .        uc|10        uc       F       -      0.112
8           10  NC_025812.2     49548      .         uc|6        uc       F       -      0.088
9            2  NC_025812.2     51483      .   Mutator|24   Mutator       R       -      0.422
10           6  NC_025812.2     59367      .  Stowaway|36  Stowaway       R       -      0.948
```

`NONREF_ALL`

```
sample  chr pos strand  family  order   support comment frequency
1   NC_025812.2 9760    .   Tourist|7   Tourist FR  -   0.833
9   NC_025812.2 9803    .   Tourist|7   Tourist FR  -   0.951
5   NC_025812.2 9810    .   Tourist|7   Tourist FR  -   0.819
7   NC_025812.2 9811    .   Tourist|7   Tourist FR  -   0.942
8   NC_025812.2 9821    .   Tourist|7   Tourist FR  -   1.0
2   NC_025812.2 9831    .   Tourist|7   Tourist F   -   0.562
10  NC_025812.2 9843    .   Tourist|7   Tourist FR  -   1.0
4   NC_025812.2 9861    .   Tourist|7   Tourist FR  -   0.978
6   NC_025812.2 9861    .   Tourist|7   Tourist FR  -   0.77
6   NC_025812.2 9969    .   Mutator|21  Mutator FR  -   0.695
3   NC_025812.2 12176   .   Tourist|7   Tourist FR  -   0.973
4   NC_025812.2 12176   .   Tourist|7   Tourist FR  -   1.0
6   NC_025812.2 12176   .   Tourist|7   Tourist FR  -   1.0
8   NC_025812.2 12176   .   Tourist|7   Tourist FR  -   1.0
9   NC_025812.2 12176   .   Tourist|7   Tourist FR  -   0.959
10  NC_025812.2 12176   .   Tourist|7   Tourist FR  -   1.0
11  NC_025812.2 12176   .   Tourist|7   Tourist FR  -   0.816
7   NC_025812.2 12177   .   Tourist|7   Tourist FR  -   1.0
1   NC_025812.2 12184   .   Tourist|7   Tourist FR  -   1.0
12  NC_025812.2 28943   .   Tourist|7   Tourist R   -   0.61
5   NC_025812.2 28947   .   Tourist|7   Tourist R   -   0.49
11  NC_025812.2 28982   .   Tourist|7   Tourist FR  -   0.797
9   NC_025812.2 50305   .   uc|5    uc  FR  -   1.0
7   NC_025812.2 50314   .   uc|5    uc  FR  -   1.0
1   NC_025812.2 50327   .   uc|5    uc  FR  -   1.0
8   NC_025812.2 50327   .   uc|5    uc  FR  -   1.0
10  NC_025812.2 50329   .   uc|5    uc  FR  -   1.0
6   NC_025812.2 50336   .   uc|5    uc  FR  -   0.757
5   NC_025812.2 50339   .   uc|5    uc  FR  -   0.882
4   NC_025812.2 50353   .   uc|5    uc  FR  -   1.0
2   NC_025812.2 50385   .   uc|5    uc  FR  -   0.712
10  NC_025812.2 51457   .   Mutator|24  Mutator FR  -   1.0
7   NC_025812.2 51466   .   Mutator|24  Mutator FR  -   1.0
4   NC_025812.2 51475   .   Mutator|24  Mutator FR  -   1.0
1   NC_025812.2 51481   .   Mutator|24  Mutator FR  -   1.0
5   NC_025812.2 51481   .   Mutator|24  Mutator FR  -   0.28
6   NC_025812.2 51481   .   Mutator|24  Mutator FR  -   0.307
8   NC_025812.2 51481   .   Mutator|24  Mutator FR  -   1.0
9   NC_025812.2 51481   .   Mutator|24  Mutator FR  -   0.893
2   NC_025812.2 51483   .   Mutator|24  Mutator R   -   0.422
```

I tried to do it by loop in loop with `itertuples` function but it is not effective (I have data with thousands of rows and it is so time-consuming):

```
import pandas as pd

df_raw = pd.read_csv('1-DH-to-12-RO.NC_teinsertions.txt', sep="\t", decimal=',')

df_sort = df_raw.sort_values(by=['chr', 'pos', 'sample'])

# choose records with FR
non_ref = df_sort[(df_sort["support"] == 'FR')]
non_ref_reset = non_ref.reset_index(drop=True)

ref = df_sort[(df_sort["support"] != 'FR')]

f_r_pairs_reset_drop = pd.read_csv('f_r_pairs.csv', sep="\t")

# choose unpaired records with F or R
unpaired_f_r = ref[~ref.apply(tuple, 1).isin(f_r_pairs_reset_drop.apply(tuple, 1))]
unpaired_f_r_reset = unpaired_f_r.reset_index(drop=True)

nonref_unpaired = pd.DataFrame(columns=non_ref_reset.columns)

for fr in non_ref_reset.itertuples():
    for un in unpaired_f_r_reset.itertuples():
        if un.chr == fr.chr and un.sample != fr.sample and un.family == fr.family and un.pos in range(fr.pos - 200, fr.pos + 200) :
            nonref_unpaired = nonref_unpaired.append(pd.DataFrame([un]))

nonref_unpaired_final = nonref_unpaired.drop_duplicates()

nonref_all = pd.concat([non_ref_reset, nonref_unpaired_final], ignore_index=True)
```

but it takes a lot of time of course.

I tried to do it also with `merge` function (as in the solution from Code Different to my previous question: [How to compare two dataframes in pandas without for loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75266730/how-to-compare-two-dataframes-in-pandas-without-for-loop/75649617?noredirect=1#comment133461220_75649617)):

```
nonref_unpaired = (non_ref_reset.merge(unpaired_f_r_reset, on=["chr", "family"], suffixes=("_fr", "_un")).
                   query("pos_fr - 200 <= pos_un <= pos_fr + 200", "sample_un != sample_fr"))
nonref_unpaired_sort = nonref_unpaired.sort_values(by=['chr', 'pos_r'])
```

but the code is broken by SIGKILL: `Process finished with exit code 137 (interrupted by signal 9: SIGKILL)`.

Any ideas on how to solve it effectively?

Answer (score 0):

I think the `SIGKILL` is a result of an insufficient memory. Do you run this code in a resource handled/restricted environment? In my opinion *merge* is the best choice for your problem.

Comment: I'm not sure if my answer will be fully adequate to your question, @hrexen. I'm working with Pycharm on Ubuntu 18.04. My Dell has 16 Gb RAM. I've been working on thousands of rows for months and it was the first time I saw SIGKILL during code executing.

Comment: Data can be different. If for example you have a huge text fields in one of the columns that can  lead to a significant memory usage and alter all the experience, while a huge dataframe with all numbers can be quite fast to do operations on.
Maybe running merge while having a resource monitor (htop for unix system or task manager for windows) open to monitor memory consumption can help to trace the issue. Of course it can also be a CPU usage limitation.

Comment: I made a couple of tests and the code is running without problem when I add one more condition for merging (`on=["chr", "family", "sample"],`, e.g. `nonref_unpaired = (non_ref_reset.merge(unpaired_f_r_reset, on=["chr", "family", "sample"], suffixes=("_fr", "_un")).query("pos_fr - 200 <= pos_un <= pos_fr + 200"))`, so maybe there is a problem with too wide criteria for merging? But how to change it to achieve the expected result?

Comment: Have a look at this performance overview of `loc`, `query` versus other sub-selection methods:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49936557/pandas-dataframe-loc-vs-query-performance
As you can see query is the worst performing method of all. Consider moving to `loc` for example.